# Are area minimizing Seifert surfaces minimal genus

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $K \subset S^3$ be a knot and let $S \subset S^3$ be an orientable surface with $\partial S = K$.  If $S$ is area minimizing among all such surfaces, then is $S$ genus minimizing?